# bootstrap-multiselect add css to parent of selected checkbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to style checkboxes of bootstrap-multiselect plugin. Basically I want to add a class to label of selected checkbox. I can get the selected value this way but couldn't figure out how to target the checkbox.

```
<label class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" value="red">Red
</label>

$('select').multiselect({
    onChange: function(element, checked) {
        var colors = $('select option:selected');
        $(colors).each(function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('label-selected');
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT:
The only way I found is to edit the plugin like that:

```
if (this.options.selectedClass) {
    if (checked) {
        $target.closest('li').addClass(this.options.selectedClass);
        $target.closest('li label').addClass('label-selected'); //ADDED THIS LINE
    }
    else {
        $target.closest('li').removeClass(this.options.selectedClass);
        $target.closest('li label').removeClass('label-selected'); //ADDED THIS LINE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this using the `onChange` option instead of manually editing the plugin (you may have troubles when updating to newer versions or integrating fixes). The following example can now also be found in the documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-selected-parents').multiselect({
            buttonContainer: '<div id="example-selected-parents-container"></div>',
            onChange: function(options, selected) {
                // Get checkbox corresponding to option:
                var value = $(options).val();
                var $input = $('#example-selected-parents-container input[value="' + value + '"]');

                // Adapt label class:
                if (selected) {
                    $input.closest('label').addClass('active');
                }
                else {
                    $input.closest('label').removeClass('active');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #example-selected-parents-container label.active {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<div class="btn-group">
    <select id="example-selected-parents" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

You may have to adapt the `onChange` function in case you are also using `optgroup`s (i.e. then multiple options are passed to `onChange`) or additional features. In these cases also have a look at the following options you may need to adapt:

- `onSelectAll`
- `onDeselectAll`